# Determine how to calculate split weeks in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

Im not quite sure what the term is, I have been calling it "Split Weeks" but here is what I need to find out.

Given:

User will input `@StartDate` and `@EndDate`

`col_week_end_date` will always end on a Saturday, and is a DateTime column.

I want to cycle through either multiple or a single month(s) and sum `col_payment_amt`

Using the month of September 2010, a `col_payment_amt` with a `col_week_end_date` falls on 09/04/2010, which covers the week of Aug 29 - Sep 04.

The payment month is September, but only 3 workdays fall w/i this week (Wed, Thurs, Fri). So only 3/5ths of the payment is made for that week.

The same thing happens with the end of a month.  In this case, the `col_week_end_date` falls on 10/02/2010.  Only 4/5ths of the payment will be made for this week.

I have a particular way to sum the `col_payment_amt` when this happens at the beginning of a month, and also at the end.

*What I can't figure out is how to tell when I am at the start of a month, and when i am at the end of a month so I can apply the appropriate function, when running the report for multiple months (Aug - Oct).*

Currently if I just force them to run the report for a single month, no problems, and I have been told it is only a monthly report, but I *know* eventually I will be asked if it can be run for multiple months.

I know it is basically something like:

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN at-top-of-month-with-split-week THEN....
                WHEN at-bottom-of-month-with-split-week THEN...
                ELSE col_payment_amt END) as PayTotal
FROM...
WHERE....
GROUP BY...
```

I'm trying to figure out the at-top-of-month and at-bottom-of-month parts.  The other parts I have.

Comment: If you are trying to end up with a sum for multiple months, you probably just need to check *which* months and only care whether you are at the beginning of the first month you are checking or end of the last month you are checking.  Am I missing something?

Comment: The code is likely to be complex enough that I would look into creating a stored procedure (function) to do the calculation.  I would probably design it to take two arguments: one will identify the (year and) month, and the other the end of the week.  The return value will either be a 'real' value with possible values 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0 or an integer in the range 0..5.  For the rest, it is a question of manipulating the date/time functions of MS SQL Server correctly.  You'd then use `SUM(split_week(ref_date, col_payment_date) * col_payment_amt)` or variants on that theme.

Comment: @Andrew, if there is a date range (Sep-Oct), I have to know "where" to put the money for the split weeks.  The week ending Oct 2, 4/5 of the money for that weeks needs to be accounted for in September, and 1/5 in Oct. for instance.  I have the formulas to calculate at the top/bottom of the month, I just need to figure out a way to choose when to do each one.

Comment: @Jonathan a function would work, again, said function would need to return or know if it was at the top or bottom of a month.  Maybe if I do it in steps, create an SP, dump some churned data into a #TempTable, and then work with that data.

Comment: @D-Scott So, are the columns in your output basically a month (e.g., 2010-09) and the SUM(col_payment_amt) for that month (taking into account the beginning-of-month and end-of-month calculations that you have already devised)?

Comment: @Andrew, Yes the end result would be 1000.00 SEP, 1200.00 OCT and so on for the date range. I figured it out, I create a temp table, dump the data in there with a `ReferenceMonth` column.  With that additional information, I am able to figure out how much of the payment gets credited to which month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works in IBM Informix Dynamic Server (tested on 11.50.FC6 for MacOS X 1.06.4, but would work on any supported version of IDS, and any platform).  You will need to translate into MS SQL Server notation.

#### Version 2 - reference month identified by month number only

```
CREATE FUNCTION NumWeekDaysInRefMonth(eow DATE DEFAULT TODAY, ref_month INTEGER)
    RETURNING INT AS numdays;
    DEFINE monday DATE;
    DEFINE friday DATE;
    DEFINE mon_month INTEGER;
    DEFINE fri_month INTEGER;

    IF eow IS NULL OR ref_month IS NULL THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;

    LET monday = eow - WEEKDAY(eow) + 1;
    LET friday = monday + 4;
    LET mon_month = MONTH(monday);
    LET fri_month = MONTH(friday);

    IF mon_month = ref_month AND fri_month = ref_month THEN
        -- All in same month: 5 days count.
        RETURN 5;
    END IF;
    IF mon_month != ref_month AND fri_month != ref_month THEN
        -- None in the same month: 0 days count.
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
    -- Some of the days are in the same month, some are not.
    IF mon_month = ref_month THEN
        -- End of month
        RETURN 5 - DAY(friday);
    ELSE
        -- Start of month
        RETURN DAY(friday);
    END IF;

END FUNCTION;
```

#### Test cases

```
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-09-04',  9) answer, 3 AS expected FROM dual;
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-09-04',  8) answer, 2 AS expected FROM dual;
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-10-02',  9) answer, 4 AS expected FROM dual;
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-10-02', 10) answer, 1 AS expected FROM dual;
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-10-02',  8) answer, 0 AS expected FROM dual;
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-10-09', 10) answer, 5 AS expected FROM dual;
```

This has much the same logic as the previous version (below); it takes just a month number to identify which billing month you are interested in, rather than a full date.

#### Version 1 - full reference date

```
CREATE FUNCTION NumWeekDaysInRefMonth(eow DATE DEFAULT TODAY, ref DATE DEFAULT TODAY)
    RETURNING INT AS numdays;
    DEFINE mon DATE;
    DEFINE fri DATE;
    DEFINE v_mon INTEGER;
    DEFINE v_fri INTEGER;
    DEFINE v_ref INTEGER;

    IF eow IS NULL OR ref IS NULL THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;

    LET mon = eow - WEEKDAY(eow) + 1;
    LET fri = mon + 4;
    LET v_mon = YEAR(mon) * 100 + MONTH(mon);
    LET v_fri = YEAR(fri) * 100 + MONTH(fri);
    LET v_ref = YEAR(ref) * 100 + MONTH(ref);

    IF v_mon = v_ref AND v_fri = v_ref THEN
        -- All in same month: 5 days count.
        RETURN 5;
    END IF;
    IF v_mon != v_ref AND v_fri != v_ref THEN
        -- None in the same month: 0 days count.
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
    -- Some of the days are in the same month, some are not.
    IF v_mon = v_ref THEN
        -- End of month
        RETURN 5 - DAY(fri);
    ELSE
        -- Start of month
        RETURN DAY(fri);
    END IF;

    -- Month-end wrapping
    -- 26 27 28 29 30 31  1  2  3  4  5  6  Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct, Dec
    -- 25 26 27 28 29 30  1  2  3  4  5  6  Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov
    -- 24 25 26 27 28 29  1  2  3  4  5  6  Feb - leap year
    -- 23 24 25 26 27 28  1  2  3  4  5  6  Feb
    -- Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su Mo Tu We Th Fr
    -- Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su Mo Tu We Tu
    -- Sa Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su Mo Tu We
    -- Fr Sa Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su Mo Tu
    -- Th Fr Sa Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su Mo
    -- We Th Fr Sa Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
    -- Tu We Th Fr Sa Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa

END FUNCTION;
```

#### Test cases

These tests are equivalent to the previous set.

```
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-09-04', '2010-09-01') answer, 3 AS expected FROM dual;
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-09-04', '2010-08-01') answer, 2 AS expected FROM dual;
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-10-02', '2010-09-01') answer, 4 AS expected FROM dual;
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-10-02', '2010-10-01') answer, 1 AS expected FROM dual;
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-10-02', '2010-08-01') answer, 0 AS expected FROM dual;
SELECT NumWeekDaysInRefMonth('2010-10-09', '2010-10-01') answer, 5 AS expected FROM dual;
```

#### Explanation

The Informix DATE type counts in days, so adding 1 to a DATE gives the day after.  The Informix WEEKDAY function returns 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, ..., 5 for Friday, 6 for Saturday.  The DAY, MONTH and YEAR functions return the corresponding component of a DATE value.

The code allows any day of the week as the reference date for the payment (it does not have to be Saturday).  Similarly, although the examples for version 1 use the first of the month as the reference day for the month, you can supply any date within the requisite month as the reference date; in version 2, that is simplified to passing in the requisite month number.

If anyone passes a NULL into the function, the answer is NULL.

Then we calculate the Monday of the week containing the 'end of week' date; if the week day is Sunday, it subtracts 0 and adds 1 to get Monday; if the week day is Sturday, it subtracts 6 and adds 1 to get Monday; etc.  Friday is 4 days later.

In version 1, then we calculate a representation for the year and month.

If both Monday and Friday fall in the reference month, then the answer is 5 days; if neither falls in the reference month, the answer is 0 days.  If the Friday is within the reference month, then the DAY() value of the Friday date is the number of days in the month.  Otherwise, the Monday is within the reference month, and the number of days in the month is 5 - DAY(Friday).

Note that this calculation deals with completely unrelated months - as shown by the last but one test case; there are zero days of a payment made October that should be counted in August.

Comment: Looks like this would work, however you have a Reference Date, which seems to be the key.  As an example, I would know the "week ending date" for a particular payment is 10/02/2010.  From knowing only that date, I was trying to find a way to determine how much of the payment goes into Septembers Total, and how much into October's total when given a date range spanning two or more months.  If I was given only a single month, it was easy we knew the "reference month".  I appreciate the help.  I will take this code and see if I can use it to streamline what I currently have.

Comment: @D Scott: I'm not clear why the reference date is a problem. You have to know which month you're interested in when asking for September's total vs October's total for a week split over that boundary.  Well, that's my perception, of course. My tests show that when asked for the September portion you get 4 and the October portion you get 1, adding to 5 as required. The year part of the reference date is needed for the Dec/Jan split; the day part is immaterial. However, you know your data better, but I thought you knew whether you were looking for September or October billing information.

Comment: @Johnathan Leffler: `You have to know which month you're interested in when asking for September's total vs October's total for a week split over that boundary.`  This was what I was trying to figure out.  Given the weekend date, and a date range, how to determine which method to calculate the pay for the top and bottom of the month.  So given the information of SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE col_week_end_date >= '09/01/2010' and col_week_end_date <= '10/31/2010' How would I tell (in the form of a CASE statement or something) which calculation to use (Top/Bottom of Month)  See my answer for more info

Comment: So what I did, using a a WHILE LOOP to first run through the date range, and place the columns I need, plus a RefMonth, and RefMonthName into a temp table.  Then run my select on the temp table, and I am not able to determine which month I am working in, and calculate the payment correctly at the Top/Bottom of the Reference Month.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is what I ended up doing in a nutshell.

I set up a WHILE loop.  I loop through the months for the date range, and insert the data into a TempTable along with a numeric Reference Month column (well, really an INT), and the month name (September, October etc...).  From the TempTable I then select the data and have a CASE statement which determines which calculation to use. So it reads something like this...

```
                -- Top of the month, Split Week
select sum(case when datepart(d,col_week_end_date) <= 7 AND RefMonth = month(col_ween_end_date)
                then ...Top of Month calc...

                -- Middle of the month, entire week is in Reference Month
                when datepart(d,col_week_end_date) > 7 AND RefMonth = month(col_week_end_date)
                then ...Just SUM the column as usual...

                -- Bottom of month, Split Week
                when RefMonth < month(col_week_end_date)
                then ...Bottom of Month calc...
          ) end as MonthlySum,
       col_RefMonth,
       col_RefMonthName
from dbo.TempTable
group by col_RefMonth, col_RefMonthName
order by col_RefMonth
```

So far with the limited amount of data I have, it appears to be working with the split weeks in the months I have available.  Seems the "Reference Month" was the key, and I needed to loop through and put the data in a  TempTable.  I was hoping there would be a way to get it in a single pass, or a least a quick dump into a #TempTable and select from there.

I'm not sure how efficient it will be, but it is only for monthly reporting and not really as an online interactive report.

Comment: The only comment I'll make is that if you write that code out more than once, you have a maintenance nightmare on your hands.  If this is the only statement that will ever need the calculation, fine.  If not - use a function.

Comment: Not sure at this point, actually just found out I don't even need to worry about the split weeks.  Now they just want to count the payment for the month it was made in.  I think the easiest answer since this whole system is still in the development phase, would be to just add a "reference month" column.  Then no need to loop through the data to figure that out, only to loop through it one more time to get the sum.